# Dynamic Property Access

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out a topic and I can't seam to get it to work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Experiments</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var AGE = (function(){
        var saying1 = "this is saying 1 ";
        var saying2 = "this is saying 2 ";
        var saying3 = "this is saying 3 ";

        return {
            say: function(numbers){
                return this["saying" + numbers];
            },
            sayFunction: function(){
                return "Hello World ";
            }

        };
    })();
    document.write(AGE.sayFunction());
    document.write(AGE.say(1));
    document.write(AGE.say(2));
    document.write(AGE.say(3));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't seam to be working, tried replacing "return this["saying" + numbers];" with "return AGE["saying" + numbers];" and "return ["saying" + numbers];" Anyone know what I am missing or messing up on?

```
var AGE = (function() {
   return {
     saying1: "this is saying 1",
     saying2: "this is saying 2 ",
     saying3: "this is saying 3 ",

     say: function(numbers) {
       return this["saying" + numbers];
     },

     sayFunction: function() {
       return "Hello World ";
     }
   };
 })();

 console.log(AGE.sayFunction());
 console.log(AGE.say(1));
 console.log(AGE.say(2));
 console.log(AGE.say(3));
```

Thanks Paul for the answer only issue now is saying1, saying2 and saying3 are public now.

```
var AGE = (function(){
    var say1 = "this is saying 1 ";
    var say2 = "this is saying 2 ";
    var say3 = "this is saying 3 ";        

    return {
        say: function(){
            return say1;
        }
    };
})();
document.write(AGE.say());
```

This is the effect that I am trying to achieve but with bracket notation I don't know now if "Dynamic Property Access" can work with private access through a public function?

Comment: `this` isn't valid in the context that you are using it. More so, it seems you're generally confused on how prototype/classes work in JS. My advice would be to search the web for some tutorials on that and you'll likely figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't properties (of anything, but certainly not of the anonymous object you're returning).

Make them actual properties, and it works:

```js
 var AGE = (function() {
   return {
     saying1: "this is saying 1",
     saying2: "this is saying 2 ",
     saying3: "this is saying 3 ",

     say: function(numbers) {
       return this["saying" + numbers];
     },

     sayFunction: function() {
       return "Hello World ";
     }
   };
 })();

 console.log(AGE.sayFunction());
 console.log(AGE.say(1));
 console.log(AGE.say(2));
 console.log(AGE.say(3));
```

Comment: This works the way I intended but saying1, saying2 and saying3 are no longer private. In my previous code I could return any private member eg. "return saying1" but doen't work work with dynamic bracket notation eg. "return ["say" + "ing" + 1]"

Answer (score 2):

the `sayings` are not in `this`, they are local variables of the scope, I suggest creating a map instead:

```
var AGE = (function(){
    var sayings = {
        1: "this is saying 1 ",
        2: "this is saying 2 ",
        3: "this is saying 3 "
    };

    return {
        say: function(numbers){
            return sayings[numbers];
        },
        sayFunction: function(){
            return "Hello World ";
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that will work but I am practicing dynamic properties with bracket notation and to spice it up a bit I am keeping members private.

Comment: members are still private. And you can change the property names of the sayings object to the way you where doing it and it will work also.